# django-restframework serialize display

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

when user goes to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/movies/`,  I don't want to show the `Showtimes`
but when user goes to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/movies/1/` , show it .

I want to ask if there is method to do this??
The method I use now is write 2  ModelSerializer to display it.
Please guide me . Thank you!!

This is my original code (not the  2  ModelSerializer method)

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^movies/$', MovieList.as_view(), name='movie-list'),
    url(r'^movies/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', MovieDetail.as_view(), name='movie-detail'),
```

This is my views.py :

```
class MovieMixin(object):
    queryset = Movie.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MovieSerializer

class MovieFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ['which_run',]

class MovieList(MovieMixin, generics.ListAPIView):
    filter_class = MovieFilter

class MovieDetail(MovieMixin, generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    pass
```

This is my serializes.py

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ('id', 'title','Showtimes',)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with two serializers, by swapping out the serializer in the `get_serializer_class` method on the serializer. This will work with all generic views, including `ViewSet` instances. In your case, you can also just override `serializer_class` on the detail view with the custom serializer.

```
class MovieMixin(object):
    queryset = Movie.objects.all()

class MovieList(MovieMixin, generics.ListAPIView):
    filter_class = MovieFilter
    serializer_class = MovieSerializer

class MovieDetail(MovieMixin, generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = MovieDetailSerializer
```

There are also plugins that allow you to do this, the most notable being the one [included with `drf-extensions`](https://chibisov.github.io/drf-extensions/docs/#detailserializermixin).

These will both require a new serializer that will handle just the detail view representation.

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ('id', 'title', )

class MovieDetailSerializer(MovieSerializer):
      class Meta(MovieSerializer.Meta:
        fields = MovieSerializer.Meta.fields + ('Showtimes', )
```

This will allow you to have two different serialized responses for the list view and the detail view.